# Bootstrap modals displaying only first record in MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, express, handlebars.js

I'm using NodeJS, Handlebars & Bootstrap to build a simple webapp. It should loop through a MongoDB collection of mock products and display it's fields.

I'm displaying the data in "product cards" (refer to [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYQLL.jpg)). When looping through the collection to create the cards it's reading each Product fine however, I have a button which opens a modal on each card - which should display the info related to that product, **this doesn't work.**

**The issue** is that all the modals display info related to only the *first index* in the MongoDB collection.

Here is my HTML code to display the products:

```
<div class="products">
  <h1>Featured Products</h1>
  <section class="product-list">
    <div class="product-container">
      {{#each Product}}
        <div class="card">
          <div class="title">{{this.name}}</div>
          <div class="image">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/50×50/?fruit" />
          </div>
          <div class="cost">{{this.cost}}</div>
          <div>
            <button class="buy-button">Add to cart</button>
            <button
              class="buy-button"
              data-toggle="modal"
              data-target=".bd-example-modal-sm"
            >More Detail</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- modal -->
        <div
          class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm"
          data-toggle="modal"
          aria-hidden="true"
        >
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="parentSlider">
                  <div class="parentSlider-cell">
                    <img
                      class="img"
                      src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/50×50/?fruit"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="product-detail-text">
                    <p>Name: {{this.name}}</p>
                    <p>Price: {{this.cost}}</p>
                    <p>Description: {{this.description}}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="buy-button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need unique IDs for your modals. I'm assuming you are using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) for the functional part of opening the modals. The [`data-target` attribute](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-data-attributes) should be a unique selector for the modal you'd like to show.

Currently, you have this set to `.bd-example-modal-sm`, which will open the *first* element that matches that selector.

If you don't have a unique ID with your `Product` array, [you can use the the special variable name](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each) `@index` to get the index of the current item you are looping over. If `Product` is an object, then you can use `@key`.

Here is a simple example with an array of Products:

```js
const template_source = document.getElementById('template-source').innerHTML;
const template = Handlebars.compile(template_source);

const compiled_html = template({
  Product: [
    {
      name: 'Apples',
      cost: '1.00',
      description: 'Apples can be red or green.',
    },
    {
      name: 'Bananas',
      cost: '2.00',
      description: 'Bananas are usually yellow, but sometimes green or brown.',
    },
    {
      name: 'Coconuts',
      cost: '3.00',
      description: 'Coconuts when pealed are usually tan or brown.',
    },
  ]
});

const app = document.getElementById('app');
app.innerHTML = compiled_html;
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');


/* misc */
.product-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card,
.modal {
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.card {
  background: gainsboro;
}

.modal {
  background: beige;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script id="template-source" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <div class="product-container">
     {{#each Product}}
       <div class="card">
         <p>Name: {{this.name}}</p>
         <p>Cost: {{this.cost}}</p>
         <button
           data-toggle="modal"
           data-target="#product-modal-{{@index}}"
         >
           More Detail
         </button>
       </div>
       
       <!-- modal -->
       <div
         id="product-modal-{{@index}}"
         class="modal"
         data-toggle="modal"
         aria-hidden="true"
       >
         <p>Name: {{this.name}}</p>
         <p>Cost: {{this.cost}}</p>
         <p>Description: {{this.description}}</p>
         <button data-bs-dismiss="modal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>
     {{/each}}
   </div>
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
```